# csv reader failing on new line without delimiter

Tags: django, csv

I am building an application which accepts csv data as an uploaded file.

Here is the relevent part of my view:

```
def climate_upload(request):
    ...
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')    # news csv reader instance 
    next(reader)    # skip header row

    for line in reader:
        if not line:
            continue    
        report = site_name
        report.year = line[1]
        report.month = line[2]
        ...
        report.save()
    file.close()    # close file
    ...
```

So, this works fine on data which looks like this:

```
;"headers"
;2012;5;2012-06-01;27.1;24.5;29.8;26.8;85;0.8
;2012;5;2012-06-02;27.1;24.5;29.8;26.8;85;0.8
```

But fails on this:

```
"headers"
2012;5;2012-06-01;27.1;24.5;29.8;26.8;85;0.8
2012;5;2012-06-02;27.1;24.5;29.8;26.8;85;0.8
```

*Note  the lack of initial delimiter on each line.*

Unfortunately MS Excel seems to spit out the second version. I assume that `reader` is not recognizing a new line as a delimiter. Is there some flag with reader which will force it to accept `\n` as a delimiter as well as `;` ?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delimiters or newlines aren't the problem - you're counting incorrectly.

The first element of a list has the index `0`. So it should be

```
report.year = line[0]
report.month = line[1]
# etc.
```

I'm guessing you're running into a `List index out of range` exception on the last element (`line[9]`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :) For some reason I had a file with delimiter at the beginning when developing. Thanks again.